# What PowerPC instructions treat r0 as 0?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, powerpc

When its `RA` parameter is 0, the `addi` instruction will consider that to be a value instead of reading from the corresponding register like it would if that parameter were anything else. Load and store instructions behave the same way.

Are there any other instructions that behave like this?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180813-00/?p=99475 mentions that for load/store instructions.  My PowerPC knowledge is rusty; is `r0` not always hard-wired as a zero register like MIPS `$zero` or AArch64 `xzr`?  (Note that AArch64's `xzr` is separate from `x0`, and which you get for that register-number depends on the opcode, which sounds maybe a little like what you're describing for PowerPC.)

Comment: @PeterCordes As far as I can tell, every instruction except `addi` and those in the load and store family will treat `r0` as a normal register instead of a hard-wired zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official source for this information would be the ISA - [here's](https://openpowerfoundation.org/?resource_lib=power-isa-version-3-0) the one for Power9, the latest released chip.

If you search through the pdf for "RA = 0" you can see instructions whose behaviour depends on RA being 0. I can find:

- l{b,h,w}z[x]
- l{h,w}a[x]
- ld[x]
- st{b,h,w,d}[x]
- {l,st}q
- {l,st}{h,w,d}brx
- {l,st}mw
- {l,st}sw{i,x}
- addi[s]
- {l,st}f{s,d}[x]
- lfiw{z,a}x
- stfiwx
- {l,st}fdp[x]
- {l,st}ve{b,h,w}x
- {l,st}vx[l]
- lvs{l,r}
- dcbz
- copy, paste
- l{b,h,w,d,q}arx
- st{b,h,w,d,q}cx.
- tabort./treclaim., kinda
- l{b,h,w,d}zcix
- st{b,h,w,d}cix